# On AWS console, how to view ALL tags on a resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In the AWS console, for some resources (say for an ECR repo) there is a page for "tags". This page purports to list all tags, however it seems to list only tags without hyphens or underscores in their names.

Why is this, is it documented, and how do you view a list of *all* tags for some resource in the web console?

Answer (score 0):

If you click the "edit" button, you finally do get a complete list of tags on that resource.

Alternatively, if you type a hyphen or underscore into the filter box, more tags appear (if tags containing such characters in their names actually exist).

It's not clear to me why the initial list does not display *all* tags (although it surely purports to be doing so). Regardless of whether this behaviour may be documented somewhere, it is surely a source of unnecessary confusion.